# Big query update struct to null in repeated field

Tags: nested, google-bigquery, sql-update

In Google bigquery, I'm trying to do an update on a repeated field.

For comparison, this works (or at least is flagged as valid), but of course isn't actually updating the field.

```
UPDATE my.table t
SET my_field = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT g.foo, g.bar, g.struct_to_set_null
  FROM unnest(t.groups) as g
), ... FROM ... etc
```

Setting `struct_to_set_null` to null gives an error:

```
UPDATE my.table t
SET my_field = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT g.foo, g.bar, null as struct_to_set_null
  FROM unnest(t.groups) as g
), ... FROM ... etc
```

> `Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<... (really long and cut off) cannot be assigned to groups, which has type <ARRAY,STRUCT<... (same, really long, cut off)`

I can see that the field in question is of type `RECORD` and `NULLABLE`, so I would think setting it to `null` is allowed. Is there a trick to getting this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that BigQuery isn't inferring the type of the struct field just from the NULL literal; you need to be a bit more explicit. Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_elliottb.UpdateTable (
  my_field ARRAY<STRUCT<foo INT64, bar INT64, struct_to_set_null STRUCT<x STRING, y BOOL, z INT64>>>
);

UPDATE tmp_elliottb.UpdateTable
SET my_field = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT foo, bar, NULL AS struct_to_set_null FROM UNNEST(my_field)
)
WHERE true;
```

This gives me:

```
Value of type ARRAY<STRUCT<foo INT64, bar INT64, struct_to_set_null INT64>> cannot be assigned to my_field, which has type ARRAY<STRUCT<foo INT64, bar INT64, struct_to_set_null STRUCT<x STRING, y BOOL, z INT64>>> at [4:16]
```

What I can do instead is to use an `IF` expression that produces `NULL`, but has `struct_to_set_null` on one of the branches in order to force the output type that I want:

```
UPDATE tmp_elliottb.UpdateTable
SET my_field = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT
    foo, bar,
    IF(false, struct_to_set_null, NULL) AS struct_to_set_null 
  FROM UNNEST(my_field)
)
WHERE true;
```

Or, alternatively, I can use `SELECT * REPLACE`:

```
UPDATE tmp_elliottb.UpdateTable
SET my_field = ARRAY(
  SELECT AS STRUCT * REPLACE (IF(false, struct_to_set_null, NULL) AS struct_to_set_null )
  FROM UNNEST(my_field)
)
WHERE true;
```

Comment: Love this `IF(false, , )` trick! I never stop learning from you - Thank you Elliott!

Answer (score 2):

Repeated is an Array type, so it cannot be set to `NULL`.

Currently, BigQuery has [two following limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array-type) with respect to `NULL`s and `ARRAYs`:

- BigQuery raises an error if query result has `ARRAYs` which contain `NULL` elements, although such `ARRAYs` can be used inside the query.
- BigQuery translates `NULL ARRAY` into empty `ARRAY` in the query result, although inside the query `NULL` and empty `ARRAYs` are two distinct values.